# jQuery Unobtrusive Validation - remote validation gives false positives and settings being ignored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-validate

I thought I had a pretty bullet-proof set up for using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation for MVC web apps but a recent bug has me very puzzled.

I want all the validation to be consistent so use remote validation attributes and controller methods to cover things like unique email/username checks. I worked out quite early that it does not take much of a delay server-side to cause a false positive in your `form.valid()` call so hacked a pending validation check and an interval to wait until validation was complete before finally outputting the error messages or submitting the form.

The code below binds onclick functions and turns off the onkeyup validation for the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            // Bind events to buttons so they can be removed later
            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                SaveEntry();
            });

            $('#btnCancel').click(function () {
                $('#dialog-Timesheet').dialog('close');
            });

            var $form = $("#btnSave").closest("form");

            // Just something I was trying..
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form); 

            // Find the validator and turn temporarily turn of onkeyup validation to prevent user making the form valid before the remote validation is complete
            var validator = $form.data("validator");

            // Seems to work with the below on its own but keyup still fires validation later
            validator.settings.onkeyup = false;

        });
```

Then I have the previously bound `SaveEntry()` method which finds the form, finds its validator, and using an interval, checks if there are any pending validation requests before finally checking the form and outputting error messages or submitting the ajax request:

```
function SaveEntry() {

        var $form = $("#btnSave").closest("form");
        var validator = $form.data("validator");

        var closeButton = "<br/><input type='button' value='OK' style='font-size:small; font-weight:bold; float:right;' onclick=\"$('#dialog-Timesheet').dialog('close');\" class='greenbutton' />";
        var errorMessage = "";
        var successMessage = "";

        // Starts the remote validation checks
        if ($form.valid()) {
        }

        // Call function every 30 milliseconds
        interval = setInterval(pendingValidationComplete, 30);

        // Saves or validates as long as no validation pending
        function pendingValidationComplete() {

            // This only runs once remote validation is finished
            if (validator.pendingRequest === 0) {

                clearInterval(interval);

                //Force validation to present to user (this will not retrigger remote validation)
                if ($form.valid()) {
                    // If is valid then submit
                    if ($('#TimeSheetEntryID').val() > 0) {
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Timesheet/EditEntry",
                            data: "id=" + $('#Id').val() + "&" + $form.serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                ShowData("fromCookie", "current");
                                successMessage = "<div style='text-align:center; margin-top: 10px;'>" + result + "<div>";
                                $openDialog.html(successMessage + closeButton);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                // Populate dialog with error message and button
                                errorMessage = "<div style='text-align:center'>Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (Status: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')<div>";
                                $openDialog.html(errorMessage + closeButton);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Timesheet/CreateEntry",
                            data: $form.serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                ShowData("fromCookie", "current");
                                successMessage = "<div style='text-align:center; margin-top: 10px;'>" + result + "<div>";
                                $openDialog.html(successMessage + closeButton);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                // Populate dialog with error message and button
                                errorMessage = "<div style='text-align:center'>Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (Status: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')<div>";
                                $openDialog.html(errorMessage + closeButton);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                //else { alert("invalid"); }
            }

            //else { alert("NOT YET"); }
        };
    }
```

So, all this works well, except that during testing for a different issue I found that if you submit the form, it will invalidate the required fields as expected, but if you then correct the required field quickly enough (presumably while it is looping for pending validation, though I have struggled to test this as debugging causes delays) it will submit the request, even though you have not clicked since you were shown the original error message. So I think the onkeyup must reset the validator (and its pending validation value) or something, so the next check in the interval is valid and it submits? But I can't find anything in the documentation or various posts I looked at to confirm.

As a temporary workaround I thought of stopping the onkeyup of the form, but in the same scenario - quickly entering valid data into an invalid field - the onkeyup fires and the form submits! I guess this is related but the validator settings always show `onkeyup = false` so I can't understand why it validates and submits.

Any ideas welcome. The form is presented in a jQuery dialog after an ajax request to a controller method returning a partial. Nothing special in the html.

Please let me know if I can be clearer or add anything to help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so probably the hackiest hack in the history of random hacks but I ended up appending a covering div to the dialog to stop field and button interaction and resetting input values as below to force the form to be reevaluated by the validation on subsequent clicks:

```
// Force validation to reevaluate next time
var inputs = $form.find(":input");
inputs.removeData("previousValue");
```

This doesn't actually reset values, but it does seem to remove whatever the validator uses to mark fields as valid or not. I won't mark this as 'the' answer but it is certainly one way to get it done!